# replace matrix elements with maximum value to symmetrize a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix. I want to replace some elements of my matrix by applying the following condition: if `Xij>Xji` or viceversa, replace the minimum value with the maximum value.
For example:

```
Input_array = [[1, 5, 3],
               [1, 10, 2],
               [0, 9, 16]]
```

I want the output as a symmetric array by replacing the matrix elements according to the above mentioned condition.

```
Output_array =  [[1,5,3],
                 [5,10,9],
                 [3,9,16]]
```

N.B, For making the matrix symmetric I don't want to do `numpy.dot(matrix,matrixT)`

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 5, 3],[1, 10, 2],[0, 9, 16]])
arr_sym = np.where(arr > arr.T, arr, arr.T)
print(f'arr_sym = \n{arr_sym}')
```

output:

```
arr_sym = 
[[ 1  5  3]
 [ 5 10  9]
 [ 3  9 16]]
```